# jQuery autosize causes page jump on chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, autosize

I'm using jQuery autosize to resize textarea ([Source here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/)). Recently, I found an issue that causes page jump with afterload textarea, just on Google Chrome. I've tested with firefox and IE and it seems ok.

HTML:

```
<div id="composer" onclick="callTextBox()"><a>Click to open textarea</a></div>
```

JS:

```
function callTextBox(){
    $("#composer").prepend("<textarea id="content"></textarea>");
}
$("#composer #content").autosize(); // this is for afterload textBox
```

How could I deal with this?